# What's the meaning of "routine" in this context?

Tags: meaning-in-context

This is a part of a passage quoted from an article:

> After a **routine** health check up with your local doctor, if he concludes you are 
>   physically and mentally sound...

*Routine*'s definition in its adjectival form from [OALD](http://oald8.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/dictionary/routine_2) that seems to fit the context are:

> 1 done or happening as a normal part of a particular job, situation or process
>   *routine enquiries/questions/tests*
>   *The fault was discovered during a routine check.*
>
> 2 not unusual or different in any way
>   *He died of a heart attack during a routine operation.*

However, I am unsure of which definition is more appropriate to the context. Definition #1 seems confusing; I could understand if it states "done or happening as a normal part", but the latter part "of a particular job, situation or process" doesn't make sense to me in relates to the context, because if you're going to a check up, it's obviously not a "job", "situation" doesn't make sense neither. Maybe "process" refers to the check ups as an ongoing matter that one has to go to through out their lifetime? Otherwise, I feel definition #1 fits the best.

Comment: If we have to choose between #1 and #2, I agree that #1 is closer in meaning for *a routine health check*. However, other dictionaries give much better definitions. For example, Google returned "performed as part of a regular procedure rather than for a special reason", and [Oxford dictionary](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/routine) defines *routine* (adj.) as "performed as part of a regular procedure rather than for a special reason".

Comment: This def. makes more sense now, by the way just fyi, Google uses Oxford, so they're basically the same dictionary.

Comment: Ah, yes, you're right! They are exactly the same. I copied them without realizing that. Nice catch!

Comment: It is generally recommended, in the US at least, that people have an annual or semiannual physical exam; I think that is what is intended: a check performed as a routine part of such a routine exam, as opposed to an exam prompted to diagnose some non-routine malaise.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the context of both medicine and vehicle maintenance, a routine check-up is supposed to be a regularly scheduled event where some basic preventative measures are taken to avoid future problems. They're called routine both because they may be part of a health/medical program (e.g. annual physical exams) and because they're *not* due to any unusual circumstances (e.g. having a cough) that would make the visit non-routine.

Comment: Yes, but (stretching a point) I could make an appointment to see my doctor even if I don't have any specific problem. And when I see him, and he asks *"What seems to be the problem?"* I could say *"Nothing, really. I just wanted a routine health check."* He might (or might not) be a bit irritated, and he might (or might not) just give me a quick health-check. I could certainly say I went for a routine check-up, even if I never did such a thing before or since. So it doesn't *have* to be a regularly scheduled event.

Comment: ...in short, I think more broadly, "routine" in OP's context is *not caused by any specific problem (known or suspected) that needs to be addressed*. Which normally means that since *something* has to "cause" it (or it wouldn't exist to be referenced), the most likely reason is ***it was scheduled anyway***.

Comment: @FumbleFingers All fair points... I softened the language a little so that it's not so black and white on the "scheduled event" issue. I didn't want to make too many changes, though, since I think you comments explain the nuance better than I could in rewriting my answer.

Comment: Yeah - like I said, I was somewhat "stretching a point". Your text was always substantially correct. Not surprising, since it reflects the etymology. From OED: *French **routine, rotine** acquisition of skills through practice (as opposed to academic study) (1559), regularly followed, often unvarying procedure (1715) < **route** + **-ine** suffix.* Apparently *not* directly connected to *learning by **rote**.*